# Process state characterization in output of ps command

Tags: process, ps, nice

The `ps` command shows the state of the process (e.g. Sleeping, Running etc) as also some additional info about.

Among two of these additional options according to the man page are

> **<**    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>
> **N**    low-priority (nice to other users)

When playing around with `sudo htop` I realized the niceness value can be set to [-20, 19].

What is the threshold that distinguish  a nice from a not nice process?

Comment: Any niceness value less than zero is "not nice", any above zero is "nice". A proper answer would probably mention the restrictions on setting negative niceness values and the person answering should probably be more familiar with Linux than I am (I assume this is on a Linux system, and I only use these occasionally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481320/process-state-characterization-in-output-of-ps-command#comment880939_481320), any value less than zero is not nice to other users, and any value greater than zero is nice to other users. I couldn’t find documentation which is explicit about this, but you can see it in the `procps` [source code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/b3b7a35050e29317fa66be4535aeaf83acbdc946/ps/output.c#L801):

```
if(pp->nice < 0)                  outbuf[end++] = '<';
if(pp->nice > 0)                  outbuf[end++] = 'N';
```

If you’re particularly interested in Linux, see [`man 7 sched`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) for extensive detail on its scheduling policies. Unfriendly nice levels can traditionally only be set by `root`, but unprivileged processes can be allowed to do so on Linux by raising the `RLIMIT_NICE` resource limit.